# Creating a many-to-many relation between an entity and an another many-to-many relation with (N)Hibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a many-to-many association between an entity and another many-to-many association. How can that be done?

I followed the [Customer/Order/Product example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html#example-mappings-customerorderproduct) to attach custom properties to a many-to-many association between two of my entities (Categories and Tags). That worked like a charm.

The problem is that now I need another entity (Supplier) to have many-to-many relation with Category-Tag-Relation, which was implemented as a composite-element according to that example.

But as far as I can see composite-element cannot participate in a many-to-many relationships :(.

The whole idea of what am I trying to achieve is depicted below:
[schema http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/6315/schemag.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/6315/schemag.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map CategoryTagRelation as an entity. That will solve your issue completely.